# How to display a specific page based on the URL taken from the DB in Angular?

Tags: mysql, angular, typescript, url-routing

I tried using the window.open() function but it opens up a new window with the URL localhost:4200/www.google.com and after about 3 seconds it refreshes back to localhost, displaying this error in console:: "Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'www.google.com' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'www.google.com'"
(The link stored in the db was www.google.com to test it out.)
This is the code. I need to load the URL without localhost as its domain.

**HTML**
    
    `<ng-container matColumnDef="documents">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Documents </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> 
          <button class="btn btn-primary medium" style="margin-left: 5px;" 
           (click)="viewdocuments(user.link)">View</button>
        </td>
      </ng-container>`

**TS**

```
`viewdocuments(link: string): void {
window.open(link);
 }
```

Comment: You have to add `http://` before the link which you get from db. For example it should be like `window.open(http://www.google.com)`

Comment: @RanjithS it worked. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use window.open with a second argument '_blank'.
For example:

```
window.open(file_url, '_blank');
```